# Dynamically changing the shipping carrier name

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a custom shipping carrier that allows customers to specify a delivery date. Its config.xml defines method name as

```
<default>
        <carriers>
          <deliverybydate>
               <active>0</active>
               <model>deliverybydate/carrier_deliverybydate</model>
               <title>Delivery date of your choice</title>
               <name>Delivery By Date</name>
               <deliveridatenote>Delivery on date of your choice</deliveridatenote>
               <deliverydate>1</deliverydate>
               <deliverytime>0</deliverytime>
               <deliverydatetoday>0</deliverydatetoday>
               <deliverydaterange>7</deliverydaterange>
               <deliverytimerange>08.00-09.00 AM,</deliverytimerange>
               <price>10.00</price>
               <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </deliverybydate>
         </carriers>
    </default>
```

How can we change the `<name>Delivery By Date</name>` dynamically. I searched for a while, but didnt got any solution.

Comment: Why do you need to? It might help us understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes you have posted is from config.xml there should be a system.xml which will help you create a configuration for the admin to change the data. Please see [This Wiki Page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module#admin_configuration_implementation) for that.

If the shipping module is working then you need to change the title of the shipping method by taking the configuration value as done [Same page just scroll up.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module#adapter_model)

The both links I've suggested is for developing a custom shipping method, I think that page should be very helpful for you.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - it's not making the name dynamic, just moving where the static name is set from the `config.xml` to a configuration text box. The word 'dynamic' suggests it is changed on-the-fly in the code based on some variables. If this solved @Renku's problem then maybe the question needs to be re-written?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the method title in your custom shipping carrier's `collectRates()` function. When looping through available shipping methods, this code is used:

```
$method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
...
$method->setMethodTitle('Custom title here');
```

An example of this is on line 121 of `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate`